# how can i add a for loop to reduce this code?

Tags: python

This code is to set up a system (I send commands to the system in order to flash it but first i need to set up the environment by sending command by command and read output from the system to see if the commands i sent are well interpreted). I need to optimise it.

What could be the most elegant way to optimise this code ? I was thinking of adding an array that contains all commands and then put them in a for loop!! 
Please share your ideas!

```
try:
  ser = serial.Serial("COM32", baudrate=115200, timeout=0, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
  if ser.isOpen():
      print(ser.name + ' is open...')
  else:
      print(ser.name + ' is closed...')

  if command1  == 'exit' or command2 == 'exit' or command3 == 'exit' or command4 == 'exit' or command5 == 'exit' or command6 == 'exit' :

      ser.close()
      exit()
  else:

          l2 = []
          for c in command1:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it! "setenv qnx_ifs_name 'ifs-rcar_h3.bin';"
            l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          l2_byte = bytearray(l2)
          print(l2_byte)
          ser.write(l2_byte)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)

          l2 = []
          for c in command2:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)

          l2 = []
          for c in command3:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(5)

          l2 = []
          for c in command4:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)
          #
          l2 = []
          for c in command5:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(8)
          #

          l2 = []
          for c in command6:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(10)
          #
          l2 = []
          for c in command7:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(10)
          #
          l2 = []
          for c in command8:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(10)

          l2 = []
          for c in command9:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)

          l2 = []
          for c in command10:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)


          l2 = []
          for c in command11:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)

          l2 = []
          for c in command12:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(1)


          l2 = []
          for c in command13:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(5)


          l2 = []
          for c in command14:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(10)


          l2 = []
          for c in command15:  # in Python, a string is just a sequence, so we can iterate over it!
              l2.append(ord(c))
          l2.append(13)
          l2.append(10)
          print(l2)
          ser.write(l2)
          out = ser.read(1000000000)
          print(out)
          time.sleep(20)

  while ser.read():
    print('serial open')

  print('serial closed')
  ser.close()
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
  print ('exception')
```

Comment: Why do some pieces append `'\r\n'` while other append `'\r\n\n\n'`? What's the difference?

Comment: Also, have you thought about create a list of all the "commands" you want to send? A list that you could *loop* over?

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea. Any difficulty implementing it?

Comment: Yes, i have some difficulties in implementation ! 
some pieces append ```'\r\n'``` while other append ```'\r\n\n\n'``` because in some commands i need to jump more lines to make things visible and clear.
Regarding the list of commands, It's should like this
```commands = ["command1" , "command2" , ... ]
command1 = "setenv qnx_ifs_name 'ifs-rcar_h3.bin';"```

Comment: How about creating a function that has arguments for all the things that differ between calls? Then you get a list of function calls in your code which should be as readable as a list of commands. Once you have the list of function calls you may even realize that further simplification is possible.

Comment: Thank you @DanielJunglas , that would be also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can save all the commands to a list and iterate over the list and depending on the type of command add extra `\n` characters to the `l2` array and accordingly manage the sleep time as well. Hope the following code helps-

```
try:
    ser = serial.Serial("COM32", baudrate=115200, timeout=0, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    if ser.isOpen():
        print(ser.name + ' is open...')
    else:
        print(ser.name + ' is closed...')

    all_commands = [command1, command2, command3, command4, command5, command6, command7, command8,
                    command9, command10, command11, command12, command13, command14, command15]
    exit_commands = all_commands[:6]
    if 'exit' in exit_commands:
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        sleep10_commands = all_commands[5:8] + all_commands[13:14]
        sleep5_commands = all_commands[2:3] + all_commands[12:13]
        sleep8_commands = all_commands[4:5]
        sleep20_commands = all_commands[14:15]
        extra_nw_line_commands = [all_commands[2], all_commands[4], all_commands[6], all_commands[7], all_commands[12]]
        for command in all_commands:
            l2 = [ord(c) for c in command]
            l2.extend([13, 10])
            if command in extra_nw_line_commands:
                l2.extend([10, 10])
            print(l2)
            l2_byte = bytearray(l2)
            print(l2_byte)
            ser.write(l2_byte)
            out = ser.read(1000000000)
            print(out)
            sleep_time = 1
            if command in sleep10_commands: sleep_time = 10
            elif command in sleep5_commands: sleep_time = 5
            elif command in sleep8_commands: sleep_time = 8
            elif command in sleep20_commands: sleep_time = 20
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        while ser.read():
            print('serial open')

    print('serial closed')
    ser.close()
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
    print ('exception')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm a little confused as why you used `ord` to add the breaklines and convert the string to bytearray.

Here a couple of recommendations:

- Give the commands in a list, so you can iterate over it.
- Create a data structure, like the dict `COMMANDS_MAP` in my example, to keep the information for special commands that need longer sleep or bigger padding.
- Define a function that adds the breaklines paddings (defined it as `add_padding`)
- Use a `with` statement to open the connection, this will manage closing it. If you are not using Python3, you could close the connection in a [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) statement.
- Write your magic numbers as constants e.g `PORT`, `READ_SIZE` and `BAUDRATE`.

```
import serial
import time

# Serial connection info
PORT = "COM32"
READ_SIZE = 1000000000
BAUDRATE = 115200
# Contains the padding and sleep in sec for commands
# default is 1 and 1s
COMMANDS_MAP = {
  "command3": {
    "padding": 3,
    "sleep": 5
  }
}

def add_padding(command, n=1):
  """
  Pad the given word with n breaklines.

  :param command: string to be padded
  :type command: string
  :param n: number of breaklines
  :type n: int
  :return: padded string with breaklines
  :rtype: string
  """
  return "{}\r".format(command).ljust(n, "\n")

def send_commands(commands):
  """
  Opens a serial connection and sends commands

  :param commands: list of commands to be sent
  :type commands: list of str
  """
  try:
    with serial.Serial(PORT, baudrate=BAUDRATE, timeout=0, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE) as ser:
      if ser.isOpen():
        print(ser.name + ' is open...')
      else:
        print(ser.name + ' is closed...')

      if "exit" in commands[:6]:
        return

      # Send commands
      for command in commands:
        c_info = COMMANDS_MAP.get(command)
        c_sleep, c_padding = c_info.get("sleep", 1), c_info.get("padding", 1)
        command_ready = bytearray(add_padding(command, c_padding), "utf8")
        ser.write(command_ready)
        out = ser.read(READ_SIZE)
        print(out)
        time.sleep(c_sleep)

      while ser.read():
        print('serial open')
    print('serial closed')
  except serial.serialutil.SerialException as e:
    print(e)

commands = ["command1", "command2", "command3"]
send_commands(commands)
```

Comment: ```ord() ``` is a function in Python, that returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string
For the system to understand my commands.

Comment: @root Right, but why not add the breaklines as strings `/r/n` and convert directly to bytearray without going through `ord`?

Comment: Because the system doesn't understand ```/r/n``` you need to convert and send ascii

Comment: But you are sending bytearrays, so you don't need to convert them `bytearray("\r\n", "utf8") == bytearray([13, 10])`